# "Build Now" link does nothing

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm getting my feet wet with Jenkins and I've done *something* bad. Originally, I had a Bitbucket hook that triggered builds. When I had that in place, I could run builds on demand using the **Build now** link in the sidebar or in the view table. I decided to run job builds nightly instead and now I can't run them on demand. Clicking either **Build now** link just flashes a tooltip that says "Build scheduled".

I'm not sure what I did, but there are a couple of possibilities:

- I removed the Bitbucket hook and selected the **Build periodically** option with a value of `H H(2-10) * * *`.
- I enabled Bitbucket OAuth security and set privileges to **Logged-in users can do anything**.

I've tried reversing both of these, but that hasn't worked. I've also bounced the `jenkins` service (many, many times). I may have changed something else relevant, but I don't know what that might've been.

Has anyone else seen something like this?

Comment: The build scheduled tooltip flash is normal.  Nothing new shows up in your Build History?  Do you have any nodes configured other than the master?  Is "Restrict where this project can be run checked?"

Comment: Only 1 node, but I don't see the other option. Where is it? It's possible I clicked it accidentally while investigating which options do what. Thanks.

Comment: It's on the configuration page (same page with the build schedule settings) in the top section.  Make sure it's unchecked.

Comment: @Rob Wilkerson, `I clicked it accidentally` - to avoid it in future you should use [this extremely useful plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin).

Comment: I don't shure, but may be is there sense in trying find something suspicious in `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->System Log->All Jenkins Logs`?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see it. In the top section of the job config page I see: Name, Description, Discard old builds and This build is parameterized.

Comment: Ah. I only have the 1 CI server. Looks like that option isn't available unless additional nodes are added.

Comment: Do you have any task in `Build` section of your projects settings?

Comment: @Gluttton: I have 1 shell task that's been there all along.

Comment: Can you try to launch build throw [rest API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API): JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build ?

Comment: No, but that got me what I needed. CSRF! Enabling that protection even prevents builds called from the app from running. Argh!

Comment: I meant 1) yes, I can run the build 2) no, it didn't work 3) but the failure helped me sort out the issue. Realized my last comment started ambiguously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gluttton, I figured out that the problem was that I had enabled CSRF protection in the global security options. Turned that off and everything behaves as expected. Argh.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same symptoms, a different problem, and [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190336/build-now-link-does-nothing#comment37344283_24190336) in the comments was helpful:

> ...find something suspicious in `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->System Log->All Jenkins Logs`

For me it turned out the jobs in the Jobs folder had the wrong owner.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was that the EC2 instance I was running Jenkins on had run out of memory.

Comment: And here's how to free it, on Ubuntu anyway http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/how-to-free-up-unused-memory-in.html. I put all the commands in a cron job that runs every 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

We've had CSRF enabled for a while and just noticed an issue with the **Build Now** button in the last day or so.  As a test I disabled CSRF and nothing changed.  The issue was not affecting all Jenkins users.

I checked the logs per @Chris and found:

```
No valid crumb was included in request for /job/<job-name>/ajaxMatrix by <user>. Returning 403.
```

A search for "No valid crumb was included in request for /job" turned up ["No valid crumb was included in the request" errors all around](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12875), which had the following comment:

> Having just wasted a few hours debugging why I was seeing this: if you re-install Jenkins you need to clear your cookies or you'll hit this.

I launched a different browser, cleared my cookies, logged into Jenkins and was able to start a jobs using **Build Now**

Answer (score 1):

As I just came across this issue and the answer wasn't posted here I thought I would add my issue and solution.

I found that when I was pressing build now on all jobs across my local Jenkins server now builds were being queued or executed. I right clicked on the "Run Build" button to check the post request and got a 403 error relating to an issue with the Jenkins Smart Scheduler plugin I had installed. I went to the installed plugins and uninstalled Smart Scheduler and the builds now run. Just a brief heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I ran out of space on the host device (or almost).
To guess that, I had to check the Jenkins logs, which was fairly straightforward.

From the web UI, you can access the logs directly from (jenkins_url)/log/all

Scrolling down to the last log, I had exactly this:

```
Nov 23, 2021 10:18:17 AM WARNING hudson.model.Queue save
Failed to write out the queue file /var/lib/jenkins/queue.xml
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:280)
    at hudson.util.FileChannelWriter.write(FileChannelWriter.java:72)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:290)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.write(AtomicFileWriter.java:162)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:191)
    at hudson.model.Queue.save(Queue.java:467)
    at hudson.model.Queue$Saver.run(Queue.java:3149)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Which was really about the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I faced this issue after upgrading to the latest Jenkins version. As I couldn't figure out what went wrong, I just downgraded to the earlier version, and thankfully, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the storage limit issue. So i just increased the available storage and issue fixed automatically.

Jenkins should show you this message in the warnings, if storage limit is reached.

> Your Jenkins data directory /var/lib/jenkins (AKA JENKINS_HOME) is
> almost full. You should act on it before it gets completely full.

Answer (score 0):

We hit this on a fresh install. A new Pipeline job wouldn't build, while a plain Freestyle job did build.  We observed this cryptic warning in the jenkins log when clicking the build button:

```
WARNING: Executor #-1 for Built-In Node grabbed \
  hudson.model.queue.WorkUnit@ba0a64d[work=Test Pipeline] \
  from queue but Built-In Node went off-line before the task's \
  worker thread started. No termination trace available.
```

Eventually we found that the sole **Built-in Node was disabled**.  Enabling it allowed the pipeline jobs to build.